# Jersey WebService with flat path structure?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am currently writing an application with multiple Jersey based WebServices. One thing that seems overly complex are the paths I use to call them.

For example, a user receives a parcel for someone else and wants to let someone else know about this. This should all be handled by one basic Endpoint *ParcelEndpoint*.

I initialize the Endpoint as follows:

```
@ApplicationPath("parcel4u")
public class RefApp extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> returnValue = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        returnValue.add(ParcelEndpoint.class);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

So everything in */parcel4u/* will be a method of the WebService.

When I try to give each method of RefApp it's own @Path (but not the class itself), none is found. I have to give the class it's @Path and each method. It looks like this:

```
@Path("rest")
public class ParcelEndpoint {
    @GET
    @Path("received")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String received(@PathParam("userid") String forUser){
        return "received!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("found")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String found(@PathParam("userid") String forUser){
        return "found!";
    }
}
```

So I can call */parcel4u/rest/received* or */parcel4u/rest/found*. Is there a way to skip the "rest" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can annotate your class with `@Path("/")` and then annotate your methods with `@Path("received")` and `@Path("found")` I think.

Comment: Well, that was easy... :-)